# Why does this SQL Query return calculate time wrong?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Basically, this query is suppose to calculate the time in minutes a user is logged onto our application. Its probably something simple, but I just can't grasp it right now. The issue I'm having is that sometimes one or two of our users will have times that make no sense. Such is one user would have 23 minutes one day, and the next much less, when it should be about the same.

Example data:

```
+----------------+----------+
| ava_modifiedby |   Time   |
+----------------+----------+
| RSCHIFFELBEIN  | 20:22:08 |
| TMORRIS        | 13:41:57 |
| TATKINS        | 13:23:01 |
| MATTECH1       | 07:59:49 |
| R5             | 07:02:23 |
+----------------+----------+
```

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    A.ava_modifiedby,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(ss, ((SUM(DATEPART(hh, A.ava_changed) * 3600 + DATEPART(mi, A.ava_changed) * 60 + DATEPART(ss, A.ava_changed)) - SUM(DATEPART(hh, B.ava_changed) * 3600 + DATEPART(mi, B.ava_changed) * 60 + DATEPART(ss, B.ava_changed))) % 86400), 0), 108) AS TIME
FROM R5AUDVALUES A
LEFT OUTER JOIN R5AUDVALUES B ON A.ava_primaryid = B.ava_primaryid
WHERE A.ava_table = 'R5SESSIONS'
    AND A.ava_deleted = '+'
    AND A.ava_to IS NULL
    AND B.ava_table = 'R5SESSIONS'
    AND B.ava_inserted = '+'
    AND B.ava_from IS NULL
    AND A.ava_modifiedby <> '*'
    AND B.ava_modifiedby <> '*'
GROUP BY A.ava_modifiedby
```

Comment: Please show us the schema and some sample data with the oddness you describe

Comment: I see the sample data now but I don't understand where you determine logged-in time

Comment: I'm not too sure myself, as this is a database I'm not experienced with. I'm pretty sure they pull it from a different source, and then this query solves for total time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your an actual row example from your table, it's hard to say, but I think that something like this would work

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
A.ava_modifiedby, CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(ss,
DateDiff(ss, a.ava_changed, b.ava_changed), 0), 108) AS TIME
FROM R5AUDVALUES A
LEFT OUTER JOIN R5AUDVALUES B ON A.ava_primaryid = B.ava_primaryid
WHERE A.ava_table = 'R5SESSIONS'
    AND A.ava_deleted = '+'
    AND A.ava_to IS NULL
    AND B.ava_table = 'R5SESSIONS'
    AND B.ava_inserted = '+'
    AND B.ava_from IS NULL
    AND A.ava_modifiedby <> '*'
    AND B.ava_modifiedby <> '*'
GROUP BY A.ava_modifiedby
```

Comment: This worked! DATEDIFF was what I should be using. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are over complicating your problem with the all the math you are doing. **DATEDIFF** with the **mi** interval gives you the total amount of minutes between two DateTimes.

```
DATEDIFF(mi,A.ava_changed,B.ava_changed)
```